# htmlcxx compile error

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

i try to use htmlcxx to parse a webpage.
The problem is, the example isnt compileable atm.

```
tree<HTML::Node>::iterator it = dom.begin();
tree<HTML::Node>::iterator end = dom.end();
for (; it != end; ++it)
{
    if (it->tagName() == "A")
    {
        it->parseAttributes();
        std::cout << it->attributes("href");
        std::cout<< std::endl;
    }
}
```

the problem is `it->attributes("href");`

the rest is working fine. but with this line, i get

> error: no matching function for call to `'htmlcxx::HTML::Node::attributes(const char [5])'`
>
> /usr/local/include/htmlcxx/html/Node.h:51: note: candidates are: `const std::map<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >& htmlcxx::HTML::Node::attributes() const`

Does someone have an idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just had a look at the source. The function you want is `attribute`, not `attributes`:

```
// attribute takes a string
std::pair<bool, std::string> attribute(const std::string &attr) const { ... }

// attributes takes nothing
const std::map<std::string, std::string>& attributes() const { return this->mAttributes; }
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the `attributes` function does not take an attribute name as a parameter, but instead returns all the attributes in a map. You should read the library documentation to confirm this.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  For more info using htmlcxx I found these pages useful (since htmlcxx uses this tree class):

- http://tree.phi-sci.com/
- http://tree.phi-sci.com/doxygen/html/classtree.html